# Is there a reason to picking up objects?

Tags: crossy-road

Sometimes when I’m playing something like the Piper there’ll be a something that looks like a green sprout and when i  jump on it it disappears. Does it actually do anything? Because it doesn’t seem like it

Comment: I’m almost certain it doesn’t do anything.

Answer (score 1):

## You can unlock new characters.

Some characters can only be unlocked by collecting certain items.

> - Coconut Water – While using the Tourist (either by purchasing or
>     winning him), collect at least 5 coconut cocktails.
> - Bones – While playing as the Palaeontologist, pick up each of the
>     dinosaur bone pieces dotting the map. Complete a full set, and you’ll
>     be awarded with this skeletal ally upon your death.
> - Hipster Whale – No better place to start than the company mascot.
>     Hipster Whale will appear swimming amongst the logs during gameplay.
>     All it takes is to hop on his back, and you’ll unlock him as a
>     playable character.
> - The Totem – While playing as any of the characters from Monument
>     Valley, spot the Totem drifting down the river. Like the Hipster
>     Whale, board it to unlock it.
> - Nessie – Sensing a theme here? Use any of the UK or Ireland
>     characters, and be on the lookout for Nessie in a body of water. Hop
>     aboard, and Nessie will be yours.
> - Michael Boom – This character isn’t hard to acquire, but it will cost
>     you your life. Just keep your eyes peeled for a green truck carrying
>     a rocket. Collide with it, and you’ll appropriately go up in flames.
>     When the dust settles, you’ll have a new addition to the roster.
> - Yeti – While playing as any of the Christmas ’15 characters, find the
>     Yeti on the field, flinging snowballs. Put yourself in the line of
>     fire, and you will lose your life, but gain this abominable friend.
> - Chinese Monster – While playing as the New Year’s Doll, find the
>     Chinese Monster on the map. Catch it, and you will unlock it
>     henceforth. Super lucky!
> - Leprechaun – Faith and Begorrah! Play as any of the UK or Ireland
>     characters, and scoop up every clover you see. Rarely, one will be a
>     lucky four-leaf one, which will net you the Leprechaun.
> - Rugby Player – To unlock the Rugby Player, you’ll need to first use
>     the Squirrel. Make sense? Not really, but you’ll have to collect four
>     nuts in trees on a run, after which a rugby ball will appear stuck in
>     a tree (it looks like a white nut). Grab that, and you’ll be able to
>     join the scrum.
> - Gifty – While playing as the Festive Chicken, keep progressing until
>     you reach a snowy plain. Collide with the Christmas Tree, and a mess
>     of presents will spill out. Afterwards, you will receive Gifty.
> - The Princess of All Cosmos – A lengthier title in Crossy Road, there
>     may not be. While playing as the Prince of All Cosmos, amass around
>     12 items in your Katamari ball to unlock her.
> - Ace – While playing as Rocky, gobble up at least 50 burgers across
>     multiple runs, and achieve a high score. Doing so will net the former
>     Jughead.
> - Pinky –  selecting the Pac-Chicken, obtain the famous cherries hidden on the map.
> - Clyde – A little more tricky than his brethren; Clyde requires you to
>     play as Pac-Man, and eat 7 or more ghosts on the one power pellet.
>     It’s much easier said than done.

Information copied from https://twinfinite.net/2018/07/crossy-road-all-hidden-characters-how-get/